# Batch file text edit

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will ask the user to enter an employee ID and an amount of money they would like to increase said employees salary by. To do so i have to change a .txt file's salary field for just the employee with the ID the user entered. Below is the code that i am currently using but i cant seem to get anywhere with it as it just spits out the error.

```
REM Prompt the user for the ID they wish to search
set /p idSearch=Enter the employee's ID number: 
set /p raise=Enter the raise ammount: 
echo.

REM Set the file to search
set file="employees.txt"

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%i in (!file!) do (
if %%i=="ID: !idSearch!" (
set /a new_amount=%%s+!raise!
echo ID: %%i FIRST: %%f LAST: %%l AGE: %%a Salary: $!new_amount! 
) else (
echo ERROR 
)
)
pause
```

Here is an example of what is in the .txt file:

> `ID: 20    FIRST: John    LAST: Smith    AGE: 30    SALARY: $20000`

Comment: With the data line you show, the entire line will be assigned to `%%i` since there are no commas in the line. If you were to remove the `delims` clause, default space will be used, and `%%i` will acquire `ID:`, `%%j` `20`, `%%k` `FIRST:` etc. This doesn't appear to marry with the `echo` you have used.

Comment: In addition to @Magoos comment and answer there is no currency variable type, so you can't use set /a with a string starting with a dollar sign. Having field names in every row of your file is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @Magoo I've got it working now thanks to your help, but when i try to save it to the text file it removes any other employees that are in the file. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: `>> filename` will append to the file. `>filename` creates a new file. Best to create a new file  by using the `else` to regurgitate the records that don't match If you surround the **entire** procedure from the `for` to the last-closing `)` with another set of parentheses, you can then use  (*for-block*)>newfilename to gather all of the output neatly in a new file. Then `move` the new file over the old.

Answer (score 0):

Since `file` is quoted, you need the `usebackq` option on the `for /f` otherwise it will be regarded as a string to be analysed by `for /f`, not a file.

BTW - `!var!` is only required where the value of the variable may change within a block (eg. with a loop). If the value isn't going to change, use `%var%` (for instance, `file` in the `for /f`, `idsearch` within the block (but it appears not to be initialised from the posted code) but **not** `raise` since that is varied as part of the loop's operation.

I keep quotes out of values assigned (typically for filenames) but where the quotes are required (eg. filename containing spaces) then I quote the *variable*, eg `"%filename%"`. Following this regimen may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the unique `$` character as the delimiter:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Enable Delayed Expansion
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem Set the file to search
Set "file=employees.txt"
Rem Exit if search file does not exist
If Not Exist "%file%" Exit/B
Rem Prompt the user for the ID they wish to update
Set/P "id=Enter the employee's ID number: "
Rem Search file for input ID
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=$" %%A In ('Find "ID: %id% "^<"%file%"') Do (
    Rem Show the user the current salary value
    Echo Current Salary for ID %id% is $%%B
    Rem Prompt the user for the new raise amount
    Set/P "raise=Press Enter to accept or Type an increase amount: "
    Rem Supplement 0 raise for empty amount
    If Not Defined raise Set "raise=0"
    Rem Calculate new salary based on raise
    Set/A "new_amount=raise+%%B"
    Rem Output line with resultant salary
    Echo %%A $!new_amount!
)
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF
```

*You may of course remove the commented lines.*

**Edit**

Here's a version which writes to a new file. I'm feeling generous…

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "file=employees.txt"
If Not Exist "%file%" Exit/B
Set/P "id=Enter an employee ID number: "
If Not Defined id Exit/B
Set/P "amount=Enter new raise increase: "
If Not Defined amount Set "amount=0"
(For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A In ("%file%") Do (Echo=%%A|Find "ID: %id% ">Nul&&(
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=$" %%B In ("%%A") Do (Set/A "amount+=%%C"
        Echo=%%B$!amount!))||Echo=%%A))>updated.txt
```

*This time without the comments.*

Please understand that if your search file's layout changes these scripts may not work!

Comment: This works but if there are other employees in the text file it removes them and just leaves the employee who had their salary changed

Comment: No it doesn't, my script only echo's a line to the console; something you've changed has caused that problem. _Best guess is that you've redirected `Echo %%A $!new amount!` to a file._

Comment: Yes, the whole point of the file is to replace that salary that is currently in there with the new one. Sorry if i did't mention that earlier. So i have set it to output to a .tmp file then copy it to the employees.txt file.

Comment: I've decided to Edit my answer to include a version which outputs to a new file.

Comment: Hey thanks for all of your help but this still won't help me because it output to the same file and remove the previous salary. I'll keep messing around with it and try to get it on my own

Comment: No it doesn't, and stop messing around with it. The input file is called `employees.txt`, the output file is called `updated.txt`. If you wish for the updated information to be reflected in employees.txt you would add `Del` and/or `Ren` commands after my code, at the end of the script.